# actx matlab syntax for SaveAs: conflict resolution parameter doesn't seem to work

Tags: vba, matlab, excel

I am working on editing CSV spreadsheet from matlab using ActxServer and then saving it as an xlsx. The problem is that I usually already have a file with the same name saved in the same folder so I need to override it. I'd like to be able to override the old file automatically without being asked every time. I tried using conflict resolution parameter in my SaveAs syntax but it did not work. Is there a way to do it and is there a problem with my syntax? Thanks in advance!

```
Workbook.SaveAs(excelfilename, 51,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,2)
```

Comment: Before `SaveAs` add `set(h, 'DisplayAlerts', 0);`, where `h` is the handle returned by the [`actxserver`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html) function. This was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10134838/3599179).

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction!